# how do i show the message error without looping it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create error message when someone blurs the field the message shows his error. everything is already working but the mistake I make is in every time I want to blur the message error is repeating itself so, how can I show the error message without looping this process.

custom.js

```
// Show input required error
var input = $(".tab-content input");
input.blur(function ()
{
    if (!$(this).val())
    {
        var attr = $(this).attr('required');
        if (attr == 'required')
        {
            var msg = $(this).attr('placeholder');
            if (msg != undefined)
            {
                $(this).after("<p class='error-message'>" + msg + ' is a required field !' + "</p>");
                console.log("error");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).siblings("p.error-message").empty();
        $(this).siblings("p.error-message").css("display", "none");
    }
});
```

**Edit:**

register.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %} Register {% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class="register">
    <!-- Message Error -->
    {% if messages %}
        <div class="container">
            {% for message in messages %}
                {% if 'rm_account' in message.tags %}
                    <div class="alert alert-success text-success">
                        {{ message }}
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
    <!-- Header -->
    <div class="header text-center">
            <h2>Register New Account</h2>
    </div>
    <!-- Signup -->
    <div class="container sign-in-up">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <div class="wall">
                <br>
                <!-- Nav tabs -->
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="new">
                        <br>
                            <form method="post">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="right-inner-addon">
                                    {% for field in form %}
                                        {% if form.errors %}
                                            {% for error in field.errors %}
                                            <div class="text-danger">
                                                <strong>{{ error }}</strong>
                                            </div>
                                            {% endfor %}
                                        {% endif %}
                                    {{ field }}
                                    {% endfor %}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <hr>
                                <div class="tab-content">
                                    <div class="tab-pane fade in active text-center" id="pp">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Create Account</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    {% include 'base_footer.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a  [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: sorry I do not understand what do you mean exactly "reproducible example" if you see any mistake you can notice me and I'll modify it

Comment: We want to see your HTML as well so that we can reproduce this example to give out a proper solution. Looking at the code above does not help much. :)

Comment: Well your if statements are a bit weird. There is just one option the if can get, and thats always true. You set: var attr = $(this).attr('required'); and then check if it actually is "required" with your next if statement. Since you set it required just before that if it would never be anything else right? I think you can remove the if and var attr. Same for  var msg. Also I think your input.blur just gets triggered multiple times because the user (probably you in this case) is clicking in it and next to it. If this is what you mean with looping then I think I know the solution.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I think this is enough code, but just not an well explained question. As you now see in the edit, you need some extra things to install before you can actually reproduce.

Comment: @Allart about your word "I think your input.blur just gets triggered multiple times because the user (probably you in this case) is clicking in it and next to it" that's true when user click on the field and get away or blur off of the field! I see the error message is loop or repeat itself so to speak in every time the user gets away from the field.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I did edit my description but I think that won't help because the message error is triggered but my question revolves around why the message is repeating itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the input already has *error message* next to it and its not visible(i.e hidden) has you have use `after(..` so the error will be get inserted after the input tag depending on this restrict the number of  times same error message inserts to particular inputs or you just remove error-message instead of hiding using `$(this).next("p.error-message").remove()`.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
// Show input required error
var input = $(".tab-content input");
input.blur(function() {

  if (!$(this).val()) {
    var attr = $(this).attr('required');
    if (attr == 'required') {
      var msg = $(this).attr('placeholder');
      if (msg != undefined) {
        //check if the next to this input i.e : p tag is not visible 
        if (!$(this).next("p.error-message").is(':visible')) {
          $(this).after("<p class='error-message'>" + msg + ' is a required field !' + "</p>");
          console.log("error")
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    //hide next p tag
    $(this).next("p.error-message").empty();
    $(this).next("p.error-message").css("display", "none");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header text-center">
  <h2>Register New Account</h2>
</div>
<div class="container sign-in-up">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
      <div class="wall">
        <br>
        <!-- Nav tabs -->
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="new">
            <br>
            <form method="post">

              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="right-inner-addon">

                  <div class="text-danger">
                    <strong></strong>
                  </div>
                  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" required="required">
                  <div class="text-danger">
                    <strong></strong>
                  </div>
                  <input type="text" name="something" placeholder="abdscd" required="required">
                  <div class="text-danger">
                    <strong></strong>
                  </div>
                  <input type="text" name="somehting" placeholder="abdscddd" required="required">
                </div>
              </div>
              <hr>
              <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane fade in active text-center" id="pp">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Create Account</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should only add the error message when its not there yet. Also your if's are kinda useless exept for the first one. This is how your code would look like.

```
// Show input required error
var input = $(".tab-content input");
input.blur(function() {
    if (!$(this).val())
    {
        // If no text in error message element then add error message.
        if ($(this).siblings("p.error-message").text().length == 0) { 
            $(this).after("<p class='error-message'>" + msg + ' is a required field !' + "</p>");
            console.log("error");
        }
    } else {
        $(this).siblings("p.error-message").empty();
        $(this).siblings("p.error-message").css("display", "none");
    }
});
```

This is an solution with your code, but I think its an better practice to do these checks when you press the button create account. Also html itself has required parameters you can add to your inputfields, im not sure but if im correct they have error messages themself when its empty if you press the button. Anyway, its your project and you should choose. This is just some feedback/info.

**EDIT:** 
First answer solution may be better check indeed.

```
// If
!$(this).next("p.error-message").is(':visible')

// instead of my if:
$(this).siblings("p.error-message").text().length == 0
```